# How to creat a loop to assign a value given a condition?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, for-loop, do-while, jagged-arrays

So I have tried different types of visual basic code for this problem that i'm trying to solve but non of them is working :(

I have a jagged array for example `{{1 10 20 50 53};{5 15 25 55}}`

and I want to convert this information in a binary matrix given the condition that each array in the jagged array corresponds to a row, and the element in it corresponds to a column number. Am I being clear?

The matrix has the same rows as the number of arrays in the jagged array 2, but the columns in the matrix can go for example till 200.

```
1 0 ... 1 ... 1 ... 1 .. 1..................0
0 0 ... 1 ... 1 ... 1 .... 1 ...............0
```

My last attempt was this one:

```
    For a = 0 To noRows - 1
        For b = 0 To noCols - 1
            Do While d < jarray(a).GetUpperBound(0)
                If array(a)(d) = b Then
                    matrix(a, b) = 1
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    matrix(a, b) = 0
                    d += 1
                End If
            Loop
        Next
    Next
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a new array its values are automatically initialised to the default value of the type of variable in the array - for an Integer, that is 0. So you don't need to do the setting to zero unless there is something else that isn't shown in the question.

You have the indexes of the locations which need to be set to 1, so you can do that directly:

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        'Dim jArray = {New Integer() {1, 10, 20, 50, 53}, New Integer() {5, 15, 25, 55}}

        Dim jArray = {New Integer() {1, 3, 4}, New Integer() {2, 5, 6, 7, 9}}

        ' find the number of columns needed for the resultant array
        Dim nCols = jArray.Max(Function(r) r.Max())

        ' find the number of rows needed for the resultant array
        Dim nRows = jArray.GetUpperBound(0) + 1

        ' the resultant array is automatically initialised to zeros
        Dim matrix(nRows, nCols) As Integer

        ' fill in the ones as specified by the locations in jArray:
        For i = 0 To nRows - 1
            For j = 0 To jArray(i).GetUpperBound(0)
                matrix(i, jArray(i)(j) - 1) = 1
            Next
        Next

        ' show the resultant array:
        For i = 0 To nRows - 1
            For j = 0 To nCols - 1
                Console.Write(matrix(i, j) & If(j < nCols - 1, ", ", ""))
            Next
            Console.WriteLine()
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

> 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
>   0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was just complicating too much! It really worked the logic you presented here in my code!  All the best!